# How to Sign up using Username AND email and sign in with username OR email using Azure AD B2C local account?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

How to Sign up using Username AND email and sign in with username OR email using Azure AD B2C local account?

I tried [this sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-or-email) but I realized that when I signed up with a username, I can only sign in with username.

But I want to sign in with **either email or username**.

Is this possible by entering username and email to `signInNames.username` and `signInNames.emailAddress`? And how can I do that? (I read [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/username-discovery).)

Also, If you know a better way, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You add both to the [identity collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes#identities-attribute).

There are examples of adding identities [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples#account-linking).

Comment: is there any way you can add more detail here.  I have been weeding through all these sample policies for days now and it's really very unclear how to add a 2nd authentication method to the identities collection.

Comment: I had a sample I could use so I wrote this up - https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/another-look-at-account-linking-in-azure-ad-b2c-ea6462e5736e